# Single host connecting to two iSCSI targets - Linux

Tags: linux, iscsi, targetcli

I have one node set as initiator and two separate targets, each one on a different node.
How do I connect to the second target on node?
I'm trying to figure out how it should be done.
My initiator file:

```
InitiatorName=iqn.2021-04.example.com.1:client
```

This one is connected to node.
When I tried to add another one iqn

`iqn.2021-04.example.com.2:client`

Logs on targets:

```
May 20 11:18:26 1 kernel: iSCSI Initiator Node: iqn.2021-04.example.1:client is not authorized to access iSCSI target portal group: 1.
```

Logs from initiator:

```
iscsiadm: Could not login to
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
```

Can someone help? I can't understand why `example.1` is trying to log on to target `example.2`.

Discovery works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution. On second iscsi target, there must be added the first target initiator name with lUNs mapped to block and with auth if set.
Connected both with no problem.